# Load multiple images from Parse instantaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I want to load between 30-40 low res photos from `Parse.com` instantaneously. Right now I'm using `PFImageView` to load them but it takes too long to show the next one when I swipe.

What is the best way to load them faster? The objective is to be able to see the next photo without any loading time.

Comment: load the next one ( or the next 2 or 3 ones) as soon you see need to display the first image

Answer (score 1):

a. You can download the photos right after your app launched and put them into a singleton object. With a singleton you will be able to download them once, and access them from every view controller, so you don't have to download them everytime when a view appears.

These links will help in you in the singleton topic:

- http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/
- http://blog.db-in.com/objective-c-singleton/

b. You can use one of the Parse cache policies, check them [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-caching/iOS%5C).

Comment: @shikaka just let me know if something is not clear.